# append info to existing file line by line using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that looks in a report (A.txt) and compiles information and sends the result to a new file (B.txt).  The script is set to run every 5 minutes and the report (A.txt) changes during that time frame.  I'd like for the script to concatenate the results to the right of each line (possibly separated by a comma, but could also just be a space if simpler) instead of at the bottom of the file.

Here is my current script :

```
type A.txt | find "3," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "48," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "49," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "50," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "51," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "52," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "53," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "201," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "202," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "311," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "321," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "332," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "401," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "402," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "501," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "502," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "601," /c /i >> B.txt
type A.txt | find "701," /c /i >> B.txt
```

Output example :

```
3,3
25,24
16,17
13,12
7,8
0,0
3,3
0,1
0,2
7,8
1,1
5,5
3,2
7,2
1,0
0,1
0,1
1,1
```

After the 3rd iteration, there would be a 3rd column with different results.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET /a line=0
DEL q28368239C.txt >NUL 2>nul
IF EXIST q28368239B.txt (SET "raw=") ELSE (SET "raw=Y")
FOR %%a IN (3 48 49 50 51 52 53 201) DO (
 FOR /f %%q IN ('type q28368239A.txt^|FIND /i /c "%%a," ') DO (
  IF DEFINED raw (>>q28368239C.txt ECHO(%%q
  ) ELSE (
   CALL :process %%q
   SET /a line +=1
  )
 )
)

MOVE /y q28368239C.txt q28368239B.txt >nul
TYPE q28368239B.txt

GOTO :EOF
:process
IF %line% neq 0 (SET "skip#=skip=%line%")
FOR /f "tokens=*%skip#%" %%b IN (q28368239B.txt) DO >>q28368239C.txt ECHO(%%b,%1&GOTO :eof
GOTO :eof
```

I used files named `q28368239A.txt` containing data for my testing, `q28368239B.txt` for the output data and `q28368239C.txt` for a temporary file.

Essentially, if the `B` file does not exist, then output will be in `raw` format ie. numeric only)

Look for each of the required strings (I truncated the list for testing) and assign the count to `%%q`

Output `%%q` directly to the tempfile if `B` was not found, otherwise call the procedure `:process` passing the count `%%q` as the first parameter, examine `B` skipping 0 to %line% (count-of-lines) lines (special : skip=0 doesn't work) and appending the count to the existing line.

And done!

Note: using `3` as a data item would mean that any `3,` in the file (the `,` is added in the `FIND` command) would be counted as `3` - and that means `3,` and `13,` and `103,` etc  just pointing that out...

Comment: @dbenham - Intriguing phenomenon with this one. Just before posting, I noted that I'd left `%%q` in the `echo` in `:process` instead of `%1` - and it worked! A simple `echo` of `%%a` and `%%q` within `:process` showed `"%a %q"` as expected, but if the echo was controlled by the `for` loop in the procedure, the **values** of `%%a` and `%%q` were available...!??

Comment: See [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3457&p=17374#p17374) for an explanation of this point...

Comment: `for` replaceable parameters are global  but its contents can not be retrieved from the general parser. The `for` command uses its own parser to handle replaceable parameter substitution, that are stored in  its own table. After the full `for` is parsed by the general parser, for each iteration, there is a new variable substitution phase for the replaceable parameters in the code inside the `do` clause, this substitution is handled by the `for` internal parser that have access to the replaceable parameters table.

Comment: @Aacini: Hmm - Not something I've tripped over in nearly 20 years of NT-batching. Would seem to be a matter to be kept a closely-guarded secret with potential for abuse and obfuscation in inexperienced (and experienced) hands...

Comment: Well played, that's exactly what I needed!!  Just to clarify, the file is the temporary file, not the file B as mentioned in the later paragraphs.

Comment: @MCND: It seems that when a `for` command executes, it _copies_ the current FOR parameters table instead of _create_ a new empty one. At least, this is the behavior suggested by the observations...  Magoo: and it may cause subtle bugs very difficult to find!

Comment: Three files are involved. I use the SO question number to identify the files, that way I don't have to keep regenerating "file1.txt"  for the hundred-and-one questions I answer that use that filename. My `q28368239A.txt` is your "A.txt", my `q28368239B.txt` is your `B.txt` and my `q28368239C.txt` is a file used temporarily for building the new version of `q28368239B.txt` The code builds a new version and `MOVE`s the new version `q28368239C.txt` over `q28368239B.txt`, which deletes the original `q28368239B.txt` then renames `q28368239C.txt` to `q28368239B.txt` The choice of filenames is yours.

Comment: @Aacini, just to be precise, there is no copy.  When a `for` command is executed a new position is added to the table (and removed when finished) to handle the replaceable parameter (RP) references. When RP substitution needs to be done, the table is iterated, but to optimize search, as last defined RPs have higher probability to be requested, the table is iterated backwards, so later defined RPs with a duplicate letter hide the previous defined RPs with the same letter.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution I assumed that you want NOT the first number of each find in all columns, but just in the first one...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "values=3, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,"

if not exist B.txt (

   rem Create B.txt for the first time
   findstr /L "%values%" test.txt > B.txt

) else (

   rem Join new values at right side of existent ones
   < B.txt (

      rem Get the new lines
      for /F "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('findstr /L "%values%" test.txt') do (
         rem Read an existent line
         set /P "line="
         rem Show old line and new value joined by a comma
         echo !line!,%%a
      )

   ) > B.new
   move /Y B.new B.txt > NUL

)
```